# problem in print list and memory location show

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a list ( see below code ) but I get memory location

```
finallist = []
list_upper = []
list1 = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'book']
finallist = [word[0] for word in list1]
print(finallist)
list_upper = [i.upper for i in finallist]
print(list_upper)
```

But the result :

```
['t', 'i', 'a', 'b']
[<built-in method upper of str object at 0x00000000004D85E0>, <built-in 
method upper of str object at 0x000000000051B730>,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function by appending `()` at the end:

```
list_upper = [i.upper() for i in finallist]
```